# openssl bad decrypt failing build on travis-ci.com but working on travis-ci.org

Tags: openssl, travis-ci

I did a little reading beforehand on the [weird relationship between travis-ci.com and travis-ci.org](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/4305) so for whatever reason my github repository seems to be building on both websites.

I am decrypting credentials stored in a `credentials.tar.gz.enc` file, which was generated with the following command `travis encrypt-file credentials.tar.gz --org -r *******/******` and I am aware that there is an alternate `--pro` (.com) flag to use instead of `--org`.

My hunch is that that command makes my enc file exclusively decodable by the .org version of travis-ci, and I'm actually running the same build (optimized for only one of .org/.com) on both websites.

(as pictured)

[image]

So what's the right way to go about fixing this failing build issue? Should I abandon one version, and if so, which one? The end goal should be that I only get one travis-ci check instead of the two currently, right?

**travis-ci.com**

```
$ openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_d80a2d296111_key -iv $encrypted_d80a2d296111_iv -in credentials.tar.gz.enc -out credentials.tar.gz -d
bad decrypt
140199772653208:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:534:
The command "openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_d80a2d296111_key -iv $encrypted_d80a2d296111_iv -in credentials.tar.gz.enc -out credentials.tar.gz -d" failed and exited with 1 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

**travis-ci.org**

```
$ openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_d80a2d296111_key -iv $encrypted_d80a2d296111_iv -in credentials.tar.gz.enc -out credentials.tar.gz -d
...
Done. Your build exited with 0.
```